How to "store" the latest value from a longer timeframe?
I am trying to add a filter in a script with a 5 minutes timeframe that filters for the latest available 15 minutes MACD trend. How do I store the latest returned value from the 15 min timeframe until a new value is available?  So if MACD is angling down in the 15 min timeframe, I would like apply that as a filter in my (5 min) script until MACD starts to angle up again (15 min).
I made a start but got stuck ...
// *** Filter for 15 min MACD

// Time Frame for LT MACD
LT = '15'

// Calculate MACD for LT (15-minute) time frame using closed bars
fastMA_LT = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, LT, ta.ema(close, fastLength),    lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
slowMA_LT = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, LT, ta.ema(close, slowLength),   lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
LT_macd = fastMA_LT - slowMA_LT

// Determine if the LT MACD is increasing or decreasing
isUpTrend = LT_macd > nz(LT_macd[1])
isDownTrend = LT_macd < nz(LT_macd[1])


If you want to store a value and keep its value until you explicitly modify it, you can use the var keyword.

var
var is the keyword used for assigning and one-time initializing of the
variable.

Also, you can directly pass macd to request.security() and retrieve a tuple.
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, LT, ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9))


Thanks!  Could you possibly share an example of how var could be applied in my context?

What exactly do you want to do? And why do you need to store this value?

I am trying to add a filter in a script with a 5 minutes timeframe that filters for the latest available 15 minutes MACD trend. So I need to store the latest returned value from the 15 min timeframe until a new value is available. E.g. if MACD is angling down in the 15 min timeframe, I would like apply that as a filter in my (5 min) script until MACD starts to angle up again (in the 15 min timeframe).
